# is it possible to log the name and values of fields being asserted along with conditions when using assertj?

Tags: java, assert, assertj

For example, for this assertion -

aString = "stack overflow";
another string = "stack";

assertThat(aString).startsWith(anotherString);

is it possible to add a logger like this -

assertThat(aString ["stack overflow"]).startsWith(another strong ["stack"])

..or something similar. I'm interested in logging the type of assertions and the name and current values of fields under assertion implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You should read the code of AssertJ (for your example, that would be [AbstractStringAssert](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/blob/d28c34613d7f2be402ca2a04987b17c3ded180eb/src/main/java/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractStringAssert.java), [AbstractCharSequenceAssert](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/blob/d28c34613d7f2be402ca2a04987b17c3ded180eb/src/main/java/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractCharSequenceAssert.java) and [AbstractAssert](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/blob/4295387ed0df9aef1981137035f25f3f7f04e8c5/src/main/java/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractAssert.java)) and you'll have your answer: this is not possible in AssertJ directly. Even if, in case of failure, the error should clearly indicate the assertion being tested.

You could however do it in other ways:

- Have code coverage enabled on AssertJ, that would give at least the class/method of AssertJ that were used in your test (but you wan't have the values).
- Play with ASM or Byte code manipulation to do the trick yourself.
- Fork AssertJ repository and add your own logging™: you could hack your way in, by looking at what is done when an assertion fail and add an additional log after the failure case.

Answer (score 0):

As NoDataFound pointed out, there is no logging of assertions out of the box in AssertJ, adding such a mechanism is being discussed here https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/issues/1518.